# How can I add a if statement that goes back in string if there is a number, and to stop if there is something other than a number?

Tags: python, string

So let's say I have a string, like this:

```py
string = '12345+67890'
```

I want to go back to search for that plus, and add a letter 'H', so the end result would be like this:

```py
string = '12345+h67890
```

Also, what if I want to get the latest +, so if there is two +'s, I want to get the last +?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Would `string = string.replace("+", "+h")` do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reverse split to split on the last instance of +, then join with +H:

```py
>>> '+H'.join('123+456+789'.rsplit('+',1))
'123+456+H789'
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert into list, iterate through list, when you find the plus add an 'h' into the next index.

```
string = '12345+67890'
stringList = list(string)
i = 0
newString = ''

for i in range(len(stringList)):
    if stringList[i] == '+':
          stringList.insert(i+1,'h')
for letter in stringList:
    newString += letter
print(newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked how to do it with `if` statements:

```
i = -1
for i in range(len(my_str)):
    if my_str[i] == '+':
        plus = i+1 # <- will update every time you see a + symbol
if i != -1:
    my_str = my_str[:i] + 'h' + my_str[i:]
```

Alternatively, you can search backwards:

```
i = -1
for i in reversed(range(len(my_str))):
    if my_str[i] == '+':
        plus = i+1 # <- will update every time you see a + symbol
        break
if i != -1:
    my_str = my_str[:i] + 'h' + my_str[i:]
```

As others have mentioned you can use built-in functions like `find` and `rfind`. My personal choice is to refer to regular expressions for this type of thing:

```
import re
my_str = re.sub('(.*\+)(.*)',r"\1h\2", my_str))
```